# Why does the Monte-Carlo Method Work?

Tags: numerical-methods, mathematical-physics, random, monte-carlo

I've been reading about the Monte-Carlo Method and how it is much simpler for computers to use the Monte-Carlo Method to guesstimate solutions to complex problems like the Standard Model. It is supposed to use random values. But what I don't understand is how the Monte-Carlo Method can calculate solutions with random numbers. If the guess is wrong, how can the answer possibly be right?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you sample a thousand people, how can you possibly work out how many of the population have blue eyes?

Comment: By multiplying by the percentage in a small sample. But I don’t understand how it works in large complex equations

Comment: Large complex equations tend to have lots of variables whose values aren't known for sure. You make lots of guesses allowing all of those variables to be randomized on each guess. Note that you are guessing only about the input of the equations, not the results of the equations. Moreover, you do _not_ trust the result you get after any single guess to be the "correct" result; you look at many, many guesses and take an aggregated result. I don't know specifically how to use this to "solve the Standard Model," but you could look for research papers that do that.

Comment: Completing @David K comment: Running the LHC is very very expensive. Instead of that, you run lot of simulations with Monte Carlo method as he has just explained. Then you do a single experiment. If both data agree the equations that your model predict are confirmed, otherwise you have ti start again. Obviously,   you cannot compare both data directly. If you know a little about that stuff, you will already know that you have to process the data that big experiments as LHC produces, but that is another story.

Comment: @David K So like a genetic algorithm?

Comment: Genetic algorithms are usually solving a different problem: optimize an outcome when you have complete control over the inputs. They have some randomness but it is intentionally biased toward inputs near the ones that had the best outcomes so far.

Comment: @DavidK You should make your comments into an answer

Comment: The word "guesstimate" is a great invention. Upvoted just for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monte Carlo method solves a parameter estimation problem, in fact, it works as follows:
Let $\mu$ be the parameter to be estimated, we think $\mu$ as the expected value of some observable of a certain phenomenon (for example, $\mu$ can be the average weight of a population). We repeat the experiment many times, each times, we have a observable value. Monte Carlo method takes the average of these values as an estimate value of $\mu$

In mathematical language: 
Let $\mu=\mathbb{E} X$ with $X$ random variable. Then $$ \frac{X_1+\cdots +X_n}{n}\to \mu$$
(when $n\to \infty$) where $X_1,X_2,\dots$ are independent copies of $X$.

Now, the problem of simulating (making) a copy of $X$ is solved by Markov Chain Monte Carlo algorithm.